# In Delphi 11.0 (FMX Multi-Device project) Application.ExeName does not exist. What was it changed to or was it removed?

Tags: delphi

According to their own documentation Application.ExeName should exist.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Alexandria/en/ExeName_(Delphi)

All the documentation I could find on the internet points to this, but in my IDE it doesn't exist!

Comment: Did you, by chance, create an FMX Multi-Device project? `Application.ExeName` exists only in a VCL project. For FMX (and VCL), you can use [`ParamStr(0)`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) instead.

Comment: And have you included the `Forms` unit?

Comment: Documentation should have made this more clear.  Thank you Remy Lebeau for this answer.

Comment: https://en.delphipraxis.net/ or check my profile for other social media related to Delphi

Comment: I downvoted because the basic knowledge is that [EXE is a format for Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe) while [FireMonkey/FMX supports multiple operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey), which have their own executable formats - calling it everywhere "exe" would be as wrong as wrong as expecting every OS to have drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you, by chance, create an FMX Multi-Device project? `Application.ExeName` exists only in a VCL project. For FMX (and VCL), you can use `ParamStr(0)` instead

- Answered by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)

Yes, this is a FMX Multi-Device project.